# Combining rows of a dataframe with string columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think this is a simple one, but I am not able to figure this out today and needed some help.

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
    'q.name':['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 2,
    'q.value':['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2'],
    'w.name':['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'Q'],
    'w.value':['B1','B2','C3','C1','D2']
})
```

that looks like this

```
    id  q.name  q.value w.name  w.value
0   0   A   A1  Q   B1
1   0   A   A2  W   B2
2   1   A   A3  E   C3
3   1   B   B1  R   C1
4   2   B   B2  Q   D2
```

I am looking to convert it to

```
    id  q.name  q.value w.name  w.value
0   0   A A     A1 A2   Q W     B1 B2
1   1   A B     A3 B1   E R     C3 C1
2   2   B       B2      Q       D2
```

I tried `pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=" ")))` but that did not give me the result I wanted. I have done this before but I'm struggling to recall or find any post on SO to help me.

Update: 
I should have mentioned this before: Is there a way of doing this without specifying which column? The DataFrame changes based on context.

*I have also updated the dataframe and shown an `id` field, as I just realised that this was possible. I think now a groupby on the `id` field should solve this.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas groupby concatenate strings in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117848/pandas-groupby-concatenate-strings-in-multiple-columns)

Comment: and, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794082

Comment: Can you update the question by adding another column to dataframe and its result? Since you don't want to specify the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [117]: df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
Out[117]:
   id q.name q.value w.name w.value
0   0    A A   A1 A2    Q W   B1 B2
1   1    A B   A3 B1    E R   C3 C1
2   2      B      B2      Q      D2
```

**Old answer:**

```
In [106]: df.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
Out[106]:
  category      name
0        A  A1 A2 A3
1        B     B1 B2
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I have updated the question above.

Comment: I updated the data again, but your solution holds. Thank you for this.