# Group columns based on other columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have the following `pd.DataFrame`:

```
Name | Color
------------------------------
John | Blue
Greg | Red
John | Yellow
Greg | Red
Greg | Blue
```

I would like to get a table of the distinct colors for each name - how many and their values. Meaning, something like this:

```
Name | Distinct | Values
--------------------------------------
John |   2      | Blue, Yellow
Greg |   2      | Red, Blue
```

Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Tried using `agg`?

Comment: this is a dupe, looking for it now

Comment: @sshashank124 looping over all values of `Name`, filtering the dataframe for that value and apply a lambda function.

Comment: this is really similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117848/pandas-groupby-concatenate-strings-in-multiple-columns, the only difference is that you `join` with a `comma` character instead of a blank space

Comment: @coldspeed how do I apply `agg` based on a certain column?

Comment: @shakedzy, can I ask you a question please? Which of the 3 solutions do you think YOU will be able to adapt, should your requirements change going forwards? I'm interested to hear, because while we're all happy to provide solutions and help, I think it's in the community's interest to understand what is sustainable.

Comment: @jpp I will go coldspeed's answer, for two main reasons: (1) it's very readable and easy to explain (should I need to make adjustments to this code in 6+ months) and (2) it can be generelized very easily. The performance, while important, is less of a concern when comparing the different solutions

Comment: @shakedzy, sure that's good to know. helps us a lot - thanks! personally, I don't think I'd ever get my head around using `nuinque` rather than `map(len)`, but probably because I came to python before pandas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `agg`, passing a custom `list` of aggregation functions:

```
f = [
        ('Distinct', 'nunique'), 
        ('Values', lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()))
]

df.groupby('Name').Color.agg(f).reset_index()

   Name  Distinct        Values
0  Greg         2     Red, Blue
1  John         2  Blue, Yellow
```

---

**Timings**

First, the setup -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
      np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10000, 2)).astype(str), columns=['Name', 'Color']
)
```

Next, the timings. It seems `pd.Series.unique` is unreasonably slow (4X slower). For the sake of performance, I'll use `np.unique` instead:

```
# in this answer

%%timeit
f = [
        ('Distinct', 'nunique'), 
        ('Values', lambda x: ', '.join(np.unique(x.values).tolist()))
]

df.groupby('Name').Color.agg(f).reset_index()

122 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Using `lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())` results in a 4X slowdown. Using `set` is a few shaves faster on this data, but it really depends.

```
# @jpp

%%timeit
v = df.groupby('Name')['Color'].apply(set).reset_index()
v['Distinct'] = v['Color'].map(len)
v['Color'] = v['Color'].map(', '.join)

219 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# @jezrael

%%timeit
(df.groupby('Name')['Color'].agg(['nunique', lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))])
        .rename(columns={'nunique':'Distinct', '<lambda>':'Values'})
        .reset_index())

118 ms ± 4.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Performance varies *wildly* with the data, you may want to time all solutions on your own data before deciding what to use.

Comment: @COLDSPEED how abt adding timings? 
Yours looks like `2.74 ms ± 232 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` and @jezrael's timings are `2.94 ms ± 513 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`
@jpp timings are `3.18 ms ± 263 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I am a little surprised they aren't identical... they should be :)

Comment: @coldspeed where can i find a list of all acceptable predefined functions (like `nunique`)? the docs don't say much..

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, I added some timings to my post.

Comment: @jpp Those timings are really unfair on the data. After the first `df.groupby('Name')['Color'].apply(set).reset_index()` the result is a two row dataframe.

Comment: @shakedzy Hmm, I learned by watching other users answer similar questions :) The rule of thumb is most general functions are supported: mean, sum, max, min, size, count, nunique... and so on. This is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @jpp Hah, me too :p

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), last `rename` columns and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.groupby('Name')['Color'].agg(['nunique', lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))])
        .rename(columns={'nunique':'Distinct', '<lambda>':'Values'})
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   Name  Distinct        Values
0  Greg         2     Blue, Red
1  John         2  Blue, Yellow
```

Comment: can you please explain the `'<lambda>':'Values'` part?

Comment: @Vivek Kalyanarangan - It is rename default column `<lambda>` only :)

Answer (score 3):

One way which avoids inefficient `lambda`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name')['Color'].apply(set).reset_index()

df['Distinct'] = df['Color'].map(len)
df['Color'] = df['Color'].map(', '.join)

#    Name         Color  Distinct
# 0  Greg     Red, Blue         2
# 1  John  Yellow, Blue         2
```

As an aside, I've noticed a trend towards method chaining and/or single line calculations. If performance is not an issue, I advise using what you find more useful / readable. Personally, I prefer the calculation split into 3 parts.

**Performance benchmarking**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000),
                   'Color': [''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(2)) for k in range(10000)]})

def jpp(df):
    df = df.groupby('Name')['Color'].apply(set).reset_index()

    df['Distinct'] = df['Color'].map(len)
    df['Color'] = df['Color'].map(', '.join)
    return df

def jez(df):
    return df.groupby('Name')['Color'].agg(['nunique', lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))])\
            .rename(columns={'nunique':'Distinct', '<lambda>':'Values'})\
            .reset_index()

def cs(df):
    f = [
            ('Distinct', 'nunique'), 
            ('Values', lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()))
    ]

    return df.groupby('Name').Color.agg(f).reset_index()

%timeit jpp(df)  # 100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop
%timeit jez(df)  # 10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop
%timeit cs(df)   # 10 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop
```